# Reshaping data frame with repeating types

Tags: pandas, reshape

I have a dataframe named nf as below :

```
A     B   C   D   E   A.1   B.1    C.1   D.1   E.1    A.2   B.2   C.2  D.2   E.2   F.2

122  434 345 435 566 657 466  762 123 645  
434  453 786 654 980 424 786  897 564 243  345 455 432 435 432  
234  553 588 899 533 
123  875 789 456 876 667 988  887 234 342
```

and so on ....

where the values repeat every 5th column and in the 3rd row I have no values for the second half.

The above provided values are just a sample of the original values I have. In original I have 50 columns with values repeating columnwise every 10th. And rows i have alomst 120k. I want to reshape the values so that there are only 10 columns in such a way that values append at the last as below.

Desired output is :

```
A     B   C   D   E   

122  434 345 435 566   
434  453 786 654 980  
234  553 588 899 533 
123  875 789 456 876 
657 466  762 123 645
424 786  897 564 243
667 988  887 234 342
345 455  432 435 432
```

All the values by columns should append at the bottom in the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `stack` and `groupby`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).apply(list).apply(pd.Series).T
Out[1178]: 
       A      B      C      D      E
0  122.0  434.0  345.0  435.0  566.0
1  657.0  466.0  762.0  123.0  645.0
2  434.0  453.0  786.0  654.0  980.0
3  424.0  786.0  897.0  564.0  243.0
4  345.0  455.0  432.0  435.0  432.0
5  234.0  553.0  588.0  899.0  533.0
6  123.0  875.0  789.0  456.0  876.0
7  667.0  988.0  887.0  234.0  342.0
```

Update

```
df.apply(lambda x : ','.join(x[x.notnull()].astype(str))).groupby(level=0).apply(','.join).str.split(',',expand=True).T
Out[1203]: 
       A      B      C      D      E     F
0  122.0  434.0  345.0  435.0  566.0      
1  434.0  453.0  786.0  654.0  980.0  None
2  234.0  553.0  588.0  899.0  533.0  None
3  123.0  875.0  789.0  456.0  876.0  None
4  657.0  466.0  762.0  123.0  645.0  None
5  424.0  786.0  897.0  564.0  243.0  None
6  667.0  988.0  887.0  234.0  342.0  None
7  345.0  455.0  432.0  435.0  432.0  None
```

Comment: Hi Wen thanku for aswering but I am not getting the desired output. I have recently changed the column names kindly check that . I am not getting the desired output as when I try to import he csv file it changes the same column names. so the output is coming as desired

Comment: sorry to say as the output is not coming as desired.

Comment: It is coming like . A  A.1 A.2  B B.1 B.2 .... and so on .. as it is grouoing the vlaues by each column name only .. whereas i want to do in on every 5th elements basis

Comment: @Nik doing this before my solution `df.columns=df.columns.str.split('.',expand=True).get_level_values(0)
`